# Image transform scale in mobile application not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I have an image for example with:

```
100x100
```

and

```
<div>
    <img src="someimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

then:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
-moz-transform: scale(0.2);
-ms-transform: scale(0.2);
-o-transform: scale(0.2);
transform: scale(0.2);
```

I'am testing in iphone 5, samsung, and others mobiles, the images itself is scaled, but in the div it appears to be the same size, visually I see 20x20px, but in the block in fact is 100x100, my question is how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling does not change the used space of a DOM element. It is because you can not determine the shape of the element in some transform use cases, for example translate3d.

But you can set the image as background-image, scale it to x 100%, y 100% and set the width/height of the image.

You have to use the trick with background-image, because setting the width/height only will cause the image to look very pixelated.